# Show that the area of a square is greater than the area of a rectangle.

Tags: inequality

It is a common problem that : Show that the square is a rectangle of maximum area for a given perimeter and a rectangle of minimum perimeter for a given area.
It is an easy problem when we use calculus. It can done by using maxima & minima but how we shall show it using inequality. I can do it using calculus by how I show it using basic inequality. Somebody help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is just the dual of the other one, so it is enough to prove one of them to get them both for (almost) free. Assume that we have a fixed perimeter $(2p)$ and we want to maximize the area. Our problem can be written as
$$ \max_{\substack{a+b=p\\ a,b\geq 0}} ab = \large{?} $$
and we may exploit the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), stating that if $a,b\geq 0$, 
$$ \sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2} $$
with a strict inequality if $a\neq b$. It follows that the maximum area ($p^2/4$) is achieved by $a=b$,
 i.e. by a square.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the side of the square is *a*. Since the rectangle and square have the same perimeter, there is some *b* < *a* such that the dimensions of the rectangle are (*a* + *b*) and (*a* - *b*). The area of the rectangle is then $a^2 - b^2$. If *b* > 0, this area is less than $a^2$. This proves the first assertion.

Now, suppose you have a rectangle with area $a^2$. If it is a square, its perimeter is $4a$. We know from the above that every non-square rectangle with perimeter $4a$ has area less than $a^2$, so if the rectangle is not a square, its perimeter must be greater than $4a$. This proves the second assertion.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the same perimeter: [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)